# Modern ER-Digram generator vs. traditional diagrams demand

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

Can I have few suggestions on ER diagram generators that can reverse engineer a `MySQL` database or a `.sql` file?

I know few of them such as MS Visio, MySQL Workbench etc but they generates diagrams in *Tabular* form, while I want to have reverse engineered diagrams with traditional *rectangle* and *oval* and *diamond* shapes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reverse engineering a model has nothing to do with the way the model is displayed later. A good ER modeler will let you switch between the notation used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can u name out such _good ER modeler_?

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL website: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: well i think you did not read the ques carefully, I had already used workbench earlier but it did not produced traditional style ER diagram..